# Padding-top won't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put my "Sanchez Designs......Ms Sanchez....and "Web Developer, Artist and Higher Education" buttons midway into the page, right about at the peak of the mountain. I have researched and tried but am unable to move it. I thought padding-top would do the trick but nope. Any suggestions?

Also, I'm learning web development so please be gentle. Thanks!

```css
  body {
  background-image: url('images/background3.jpeg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    background-image: url('images/background3.jpeg');
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_index.css">
  </style>
  <title>Sanchez</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!--NAVBAR-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Andrea Designs</a>

      <!--Toggle Button-->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

      <!--Navbar links-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="Sanchez_bootstrap_about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="Sanchez_bootstrap_artist.html">Artist</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="Sanchez_bootstrap_highered.html">Higher Education</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <div id="content">
          <h1> Sanchez Designs</h1>
          <h5> Ms. Sanchez is an aspiring Web Developer</h5>
          <hr>
          <ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_about.html" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">
                <span class="network-name">Web Developer</span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_artist.html" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">
                <span class="network-name">Artist</span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_highered.html" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">
                <span class="network-name">Higher Education</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </header>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Use margin-top CSS property

Comment: I've tried that as well- when I use margin-top, it moves even the navigator bar and I want that to stay where it is.

Comment: you could put margin-bottom on the navbar

Comment: Tried that- did not budge. I wonder if the navbar has something to do with it. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want padding top try
`padding-top : 20px!important`

if you want div test in center why you try padding top or bottom .  you can use a extra div and give style `display: flex; align-items: center;`

```
.banner {
    height: 80vh;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: flex;
}
```

like : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FNBF6UP5MV4S

Comment: Wahhhh!!!! It worked! Thanks, man! So I studied the code you provided and what it was is the "@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    background-image: url('images/background3.jpeg');
}" You flipped it with the .banner and ti worked! This whole time it was a CSS issue. Thanks so much man! I can not tell you how long I have been trying to fix this issue. I don't really understand the CSS properties just yet but I will pay more attention to it! Thanks again! :)))

Comment: @Alexandra welcome :> if you facing any problem in css you can share with me

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of way to add padding or margin here.

You can add padding-top to your `.col-lg-12` if your content and navbar have 2 different container by simply add another class and add padding to it.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center padding-content">
    <div id="content">
        ...
```

CSS

```
.padding-content {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Demo: https://www.bootply.com/jpU6nmgw8z

Or you can add margin to your navbar

CSS

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Demo: https://www.bootply.com/k6vGFbX5XC

Comment: Hi Khanh, your explanation is beautiful. I understand it perfectly, however when I apply it, it does not work. I have a feeling there is a bug within my code. I have a feeling it's something in the navbar that is preventing me to adjust the #content section.

Comment: I use your updated code to setup a new Bootply [here](https://www.bootply.com/6Js0OEpACN) and seem like it dose work ... and there a close header tag without open tag in your code

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding margin-top to say, the "content" div?

```
#content {
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpRQVL